# Hard binomial sum

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

How to prove this relation?
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{2^{-2i}\binom{2i}{i}}{n+i+2}=\frac{2^{4n+2}-\binom{2n+1}{n}^2}{(2n+3)2^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n}}$$
 That seems difficult!

Comment: Where did you find this identity?

Comment: In a book I have not taken up the title,but there are very long time.

Comment: One would naturally presume induction,  though I haven't tried it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Note:* The following answer is divided in three steps. We start with a short
>
> **Overview**
>
> **Step 1:** A *convenient* representation
>
> We transform OPs expression by doing some index shifting and by adding one summand to both sides which *considerably simplifies* the RHS of OPs expression.
>
> We show OPs expression is equivalent to
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2^{2n-1}\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\qquad n\geq 1\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Let's denote the LHS of (1) with $A(n)$. We now start finding in
>
> **Step 2:** A *recurrence relation* for $$A(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}\binom{2i}{i}$$
>
> We will show that
>   \begin{align*}
> A(n)&=\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}A(n-1)\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Together with $A(1)=1$ the claim (1) follows.
>
> But in order to prove the recurrence relation (2) we have to show another binomial identity regarding *Catalan numbers* in an intermediate
>
> **Step 3:** A nice binomial identity regarding *[Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*
>
> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2-\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}\qquad\qquad n \geq 1\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Note:** Identity (3) is interesting. Writing $C_n=\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}$ for the $n$-th *Catalan number* we get a *recurrence relation for $C_n$*
>
> \begin{align*}
> (n+1)\frac{C_n}{4^n}=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{C_i}{4^i}\qquad \qquad n\geq 0\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>   The recurrence relation (4) specifies *all Catalan numbers* starting from $C_0=1$ when using the convention that the empty sum ($n=0$) is zero.
>
> Another nice aspect regarding (1) is that the LHS is the $(n-1)$-st order *Taylor polynomial* of the generating function
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}z^n\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   of the Catalan numbers evaluated at $z=\frac{1}{4}$. The series converges uniformly in the open disc $|z|<\frac{1}{4}$ and it also converges at $z=\frac{1}{4}$. We obtain using the RHS of (3) and the generating function from (5):
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(2-\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}\right)=\left.\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2z}\right|_{z=\frac{1}{4}}=2
> \end{align*}

---

And now the gory details.

> The following is to prove for $n\geq 0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i+2}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2^{2n+1}\frac{1}{2n+3}\binom{2n+1}{n}^{-1}
> -\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\frac{1}{2n+3}\binom{2n+1}{n}
> \end{align*}

$$$$

> **Step 1:** A *convenient* representation

We substitute $n\rightarrow n-2$ in OPs expression and so we have to show for $n\geq 2$

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2^{2n-3}\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-3}{n-2}^{-1}
-\frac{1}{2^{2n-3}}\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-3}{n-2}
\end{align*}

We add at both sides the term with $i=n-1$ and obtain for $n \geq 1$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}&=2^{2n-3}\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-3}{n-2}^{-1}
-\frac{1}{2^{2n-3}}\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-3}{n-2}\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\tag{6}\\
&=2^{2n-3}\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-3}{n-2}^{-1}\tag{7}\\
&=2^{2n-1}\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}
\end{align*}

and (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (6) we use $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}=\binom{2n-3}{n-2}\frac{2n-2}{n-1}=2\binom{2n-3}{n-2}$
- In (7) we proceed similar to (6) and also use $\binom{2n-1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}$

> **Step 2:** A *recurrence relation* for $A(n)$
>
> Let $$A(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}} \qquad\qquad n\geq 1$$

We obtain

\begin{align*}
A(n)&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}\tag{8}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i+2}{i+1}\frac{1}{n+i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+2}}\tag{9}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{(2i+2)(2i+1)}{(i+1)^2}\frac{1}{n+i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\left(\frac{2n+1}{n+i+1}-\frac{1}{i+1}\right)\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\tag{10}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2n+1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{n+i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}
-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2n+1}{2n}\left(A(n+1)-\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}
-\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\right)\tag{11}\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\\
&=\frac{2n+1}{2n}A(n+1)+\frac{1}{n}-\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{2n+1}{n^2}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}
-\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\\
&=\frac{2n+1}{2n}A(n+1)+\frac{1}{n}-\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{2n-1}{n^2}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}
-\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\tag{12}\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\\
&=\frac{2n+1}{2n}A(n+1)+\frac{1}{n}-\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}
-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i+1}}\tag{13}\\
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (8) we separate the term with $i=0$
- In (9) we shift index $i\rightarrow i-1$
- In (10) we perform a partial fraction decomposition
- In (11) we replace the left sum with $A(n+1)$ and correct by subtracting the summands for $i=n-1$ and $i=n$
- In (12) we add term to the sum $i=n-1$ and update the term with $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}$ accordingly.

> When analysing the recurrence relation (13) we focus on the *first summand*
>
> $$\frac{2n+1}{2n}A(n+1)$$
>
> of the RHS. Let's assume *everything else is $0$ on the RHS* of (13). Then we get following recurrence relation for $A(n)$
>
> \begin{align*}
> A(1)&=1\\
> A(n)&=\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}A(n-1)\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\\
> \end{align*}

We obtain using *[double factorials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)*
\begin{align*}
A(n)&=\frac{2n-2}{2n-1}A(n-1)\\
&=\frac{(2n-2)(2n-4)}{(2n-1)(2n-3)}A(n-2)\\
&=\ldots\\
&=\frac{(2n-2)(2n-4)\cdot\ldots\cdot2}{(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot3}A(1)\\
&=\frac{(2n-2)!!}{(2n-1)!!}\\
&=\frac{(2n-2)!!(2n)!!}{(2n-1)!!(2n)!!}\\
&=\frac{2^{n-1}(n-1)!2^nn!}{(2n)!}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}2^{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}^{-1}\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
\end{align*}

and the proof is finished provided we can show according to (13) the validity of

> **Step 3:** A nice binomial identity regarding *[Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)*
>
> The following is valid
>    \begin{align*}
> \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}\right)\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{14}
> \end{align*}

We show this identity (14) using the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient $c_n$ of $z^n$ in a generating function $C(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$.

We observe

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}&\binom{2i}{i}\frac{1}{i+1}\frac{1}{2^{2i}}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}[z^i]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{\frac{1}{2}z}\tag{15}\\
&=2[z^{i-1}]\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{z}\frac{1}{1-z}\tag{16}\\
&=2[z^{i-1}]\left(\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}+\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{z}\right)\tag{17}\\
&=2\left(1-\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n-1}(-1)^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\right)\tag{18}\\
&=2\left(1-\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n-2}+\frac{1}{2n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\right)\\
&=2\left(1-\frac{2n-1}{2n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\frac{1}{2^{2n-2}}\right)\\
&=2\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}\right)\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
\end{align*}

and the last step is now successfully finished!

*Comment:*

- In (15) we use the generating function for the *[Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)* in the form

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^n=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-z}}{\frac{1}{2}z}$$

- In (16) we observe that summing up the coefficients, i.e.  $c_n \rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i$ corresponds to multiplication with $\frac{1}{1-z}$. It's just *Cauchy multiplication of series*

$$\frac{1}{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i\right)z^n$$

- In (17) we perform a partial fraction decomposition
- In (18) we use $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{n}=(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

---

> **Note:** I would appreciate to see a reference of the *recurrence relation* (7) of the *Catalan Numbers*
>   \begin{align*}
> (n+1)\frac{C_n}{4^n}=1-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{C_i}{4^i}\qquad \qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>
> Maybe the kind reader could give a hint.

Comment: Very nice(+1). Very pleased to have the solution to this problem.Thank

Comment: @user178256: Thanks for your nice comment! You may be amused to see that my answer to your question is only the second half of my answer to the question regarding [this little combinatorial monster](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140281/how-to-deal-with-this-double-summation/1200287#1200287)! :-) Best regards,