# Closed form of factorial and cascading power sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

Consider the following sum:

$$ \sum_{i =0}^{j} \left( \frac{(j-i)^ix^i \ln(x)^{(j-i)}\ln(x)^i}{(j-i)!i!} \right) $$

I can simplify the sum to:

$$ \ln(x)^j\sum_{i =0}^{j} \left( \frac{(j-i)^ix^i}{(j-i)!i!} \right) $$ 
Furthermore I can observe that

$$ \frac{1}{(j-i)!(i!)}  = \frac{1}{j!} \begin{pmatrix} j \\ i\end{pmatrix} $$

Thus:

$$ \frac{\ln(x)^j}{j!}\sum_{i =0}^{j} \left( \begin{pmatrix}j \\ i \end{pmatrix}(j-i)^ix^i \right) $$

But I don't know how to go in for the kill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note:* This answer does not provide a closed expression but a *generating function* which might also be helpful for further calculations.

> Let's consider OPs sum by exchanging for (my) convenience $i,j$ with $n,k$ and ignoring the factor $\ln(x)^n$.
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n!}&\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^kx^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}x^{n-k}
> \end{align*}

Let $A(z)$ denote the generating function of OPs expression (1). We show

> The following is valid:
>
> \begin{align*}
>  A(z) &:= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}x^{n-k}\right)z^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\exp\left(ze^{xz}\right)
>  \end{align*}

**Intermezzo:** *[Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials)*

According to Louis Comtet's *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* section 3.3 ([3a']) the *partial Bell polynomials* $B_{n,k}=B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n-k+1})$ are defined via

> \begin{align*}
> B_{n,k}=\frac{n!}{k!}[t^n]\left(\sum_{m\geq 1}x_m\frac{t^m}{m!}\right)^k
> \end{align*}

We use the [coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216) operator $[t^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $t^n$ in the formal power series.

The specific case $B_{n,k}=B_{n,k}(1,2,\ldots,n-k+1)$ yields:

\begin{align*}
B_{n,k}&=\frac{n!}{k!}[t^n]\left(\sum_{m\geq 1}m\frac{t^m}{m!}\right)^k\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!}[t^n]\left(t\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{t^{m}}{m!}\right)^k\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!}[t^{n}]t^k\exp(kt)\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!}[t^{n-k}]\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(kt)^{m}}{m!}\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!}\frac{k^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}\\
&=\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

We observe the *partial Bell polynomials* $B_{n,k}(1,2,\ldots,n-k+1)=\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}$ are the link between OPs expression and the path to finding the generating function $A(z)$.

> Using the expression (3) in (1) we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n&\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}x^{n-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}[t^{n-k}]e^{kt}x^{n-k}\\
> &=x^n[t^n]\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{te^t}{x}\right)^k\frac{1}{k!}\tag{4}\\
> &=x^n[t^n]\exp\left(\frac{te^t}{x}\right)\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

In (4) we changed the upper limit of the index $k$ from $n$ to $\infty$ which does not contribute anything (just adding $0$'s).

> From the last expression (5) we finally get
>
> \begin{align*}
>  A(z) &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}x^{n-k}\right)z^n\\
>  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(x^n[t^n]\exp\left(\frac{te^t}{x}\right)\right)z^n\tag{6}\\
>  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left([t^n]\exp\left(\frac{te^t}{x}\right)\right)(xz)^n\\
>  &=\exp\left(\frac{xze^{xz}}{x}\right)\tag{7}\\
>  &=\exp\left(ze^{xz}\right)\\
>  &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
>  \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (6) we use expression (5)
- In (7) we use a *substitution rule* for formal power series:

$$A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left([t^n]A(t)\right)z^n$$

Comment: So i'm guessing there isn't a closed form for this? If there is, what is the natural way to convert a generating function into a closed form?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Maybe not a satisfactory answer, but the best I can give at the moment: I recommend reading the first section in R.P.Stanleys *[Enumerative Combinatorics](http://www.amazon.com/Enumerative-Combinatorics-Cambridge-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/1107602629)* "How to count" - He provides us with about 10 small examples and only the simplest has a closed form. The others are represented via generating functions or recurrence relations or by other means and we are invited to accept these more complex structures as *basic building* blocks for further analysis.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: I also think that there is no *unique natural* way to find a closed form. It mostly depends on  the existing knowledge, routine and techniques. Let's have a look at the three answers so far. They all are different, interesting and could be part of one's repertoire. So each derivation could be regarded as *natural approach*. The same holds for different ways to derive a closed form (in case a closed form really exists).

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. A hint which might be of interest for you: Today I've answered *[this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140281/how-to-deal-with-this-double-summation/1200287#1200287)* which provides some different techniques around how to find a closed formula. Best regards,

Answer (score 4):

Here  is  an  alternate  derivation  of  the  generating  function  by
@MarkusScheuer.

Suppose we are trying to evaluate
$$A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (kx)^{n-k}.$$

Introduce the integral representation
$$(kx)^{n-k}
= \frac{(n-k)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=R} \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}} \exp(kxw) \; dw.$$
which certainly holds for $0\lt R\lt \infty.$

This yields
$$A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}
\frac{(n-k)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=|z|+\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-k+1}} \exp(kxw) \; dw$$

or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=|z|+\epsilon}
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^n}{w^{n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \exp(kxw) w^k \; dw.$$

This is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=|z|+\epsilon}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \exp(kxw) w^k
\sum_{n\ge k} \frac{z^n}{w^{n+1}} \; dw.$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=|z|+\epsilon}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \exp(kxw) w^k \frac{z^k}{w^k}
\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^n}{w^{n+1}} \; dw.$$
Note that the second sum converges in the chosen annulus 
$|w|\gt |z|$
which means we may continue to simplify to obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=|z|+\epsilon}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{k!} \exp(kxw) z^k 
\frac{1}{w} \frac{1}{1-z/w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=|z|+\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w-z} \exp(z\exp(xw))\; dw.$$

By the Cauchy Residue Theorem the pole at $w=z$ contributes
$$\exp(z e^{xz})$$
which was to be shown.

Answer (score 3):

Let us write $y=\ln x$. The question is equivalent to compute 
$$a_j(x)=\sum_{i=0}^j\frac{(j-i)^i\;x^i}{(j-i)!\;i!}.$$
An elegant method is to use, as already said, the generating function
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j(x) y^j=\sum_{j=0}^\infty y^j\sum_{i=0}^j \frac{(j-i)^i}{(j-i)!}\frac{x^i}{i!}.$$

Using the little diagram 
$$j\uparrow \begin{array}{cccc}\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\bullet\\
\bullet&\bullet&\bullet&\\
\bullet&\bullet&&\\
\bullet&&&\\&\overrightarrow{i}&&\end{array}$$
we can swap the sums as follows 
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^j=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=i}^\infty,$$ and obtain, after setting $k=j-i$
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^ix^iy^i}{i!}\frac{y^k}{k!}.$$
Performing the sum over $i$ first we obtain $f(x,y)=\sum_k\exp(xyk)\frac{y^k}{k!}$ and easily get the final result
$$f(x,y)=\exp\left(y\mathrm{e}^{xy}\right).$$
We note that if $y=\ln x$, $f(x,\ln x)=x^{x^x}$.
The required result can be expressed as
$$y^j \left[y^j\right]\exp(y\mathrm{e}^{xy}).$$

Comment: Thats very interesting! I had arrived at this sum via the exponent tower $$x^{x^x}$$ I was hoping I could find a closed form to re-express $$x^{x^x}$$ in terms of 3 and x solely, based on the previous two responses it appears that won't be trivial to do