# Counting the number of ways three dice can sum to $n$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, generating-functions

I want to count in how many ways three dice can sum to a given number without brute forcing it. In fact, I would like to do it using generating functions and without having to expand out the product.

To do this, I have thought of making a differential equation out of $y=(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$ and then solving the equation through the use of power series, or getting the $n$th taylor coefficient from the equation. 

What I attempted was:
$$y=(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$$
$$y'=3y^{2/3}(1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4+6x^5)$$
Then, by setting $x=0$ we see $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=0$, which is what I want, however, when trying to obtain $y''(0)$ by differentiating both sides, I get division by $0$ on the RHS. 

Am I making a mistake in the set up or is calculating the expression through the use of a differenrial equation impossible?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Let $f(x)=g(x)^3$, where $g(x)=x+x^2+\cdots+x^6$.  Then $f''(x)=6g(x)g'(x)^2+3g(x)^2g''(x)$. Evaluate at $x=0$ to get $f''(0)=0$.

Comment: I am trying to get to the coefficients faster by using a power series method on the differential equation instead of just extracting the coefficients through derivatives.

Comment: Have you tried your method with two dice?

Comment: You get $f'(x)=3g(x)^2g'(x)$. Multiply with $g(x)$ to obtain $g(x)f'(x)=3f(x)g'(x)$ which is now linear in the coefficients of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach. We could at first  transform  $y(x)$ so that an expansion *after that* becomes less cumbersome. Maybe this variant is also useful for your needs.

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. We also use *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* 
\begin{align*}
[[P(x)]]=\begin{cases}
1&\qquad P(x) \ \text{  true}\\
0&\qquad P(x) \ \text{ false}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
This way we can treat multiple cases in one expression.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]y(x)&=[x^n](x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3\\
> &=[x^n]x^3(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^3\\
> &=[x^{n-3}][[n\geq 3]]\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^3\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{n-3}][[n\geq 3]](1-3x^6+3x^{12}-x^{18})\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-3}{j}(-x)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{n-3}][[n\geq 3]]-3[x^{n-9}][[n\geq 9]]\right.\\
> &\qquad\quad\left.+3[x^{n-15}][[n\geq 15]-[x^{n-21}][[n\geq 21]\right)
> \sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{n-1}{2}[[n\geq 3]]-3\binom{n-7}{2}[[n\geq 9]]\\
> &\qquad\quad+3\binom{n-13}{2}[[n\geq 15]]-\binom{n-19}{2}[[n\geq 21]]\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *coefficient of* rule 
  \begin{align*}
  [x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)
  \end{align*}
  and we use the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*. Since there is no contribution to the coefficient of $x^n$ if $n<3$ we respect this by using $[[n\geq 3]]$.
- In (2) we expand the binomial and we also expand $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}$ using the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and we use the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we select the coefficient of $x^{n-k}, k\in\{3,9,15,21\}$.

**Note:** The usage of the Iverson brackets covers the general case. If we need to calculate a specific case only, the calculation becomes even more straight forward.

> **Example:** $[x^{10}]y(x)$
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^{10}]y(x)&=[x^{10}](x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3\\
> &=[x^7]\left(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}\right)^3\\\
> &=[x^7](1-3x^6)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-3}{j}(-x)^j\\
> &=\left([x^7]-3[x]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{2}x^j\\
> &=\binom{9}{2}-3\binom{3}{2}\\
> &=27
> \end{align*}

Comment: In $(3)$ why do we get the binomial between $(j+2,2)$ and not $(j+2,j)$?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: Recall the symmetry $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$. See the extended comment (3). Regards,

Comment: Very neat solution, I like the use of the coefficient of operator.

Comment: @GuachoPerez: Great! Good to see the answer is useful! :-)

Comment: @GuachoPerez: You might want to see *[this MSE answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559612/how-to-prove-sum-s-0m2s-choose-ss-choose-m-s-frac-1ss1-1m/1560382#1560382)* for a somewhat more challenging usage of the *coefficient of* operator.

Comment: This operator seems to be very useful. Is there a place where I can check out other propertied that it may have?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: This theory was fully developed in a somewhat different setting (residual calculus of formal power series) by P.G. Egorychev. A much easier accessible treatment with a lot of information is given by R. Sprugnoli. See this (considerably more challenging) *[MSE answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140281/how-to-deal-with-this-double-summation/1200287#1200287)* which also contains references.